# Updata data in Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a data class in Kotlin where I have values depending on each other,

for example

```
data class test(
   var a: Int = 0,
   var b: Int = 10 + a,
)
```

If the value for `a` is updated I want the value for `b` to automatically change.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should write a setter that accomplishes it.  This side effect isn't very functional.  What happens if you set b?  Should a = b - 10?  Consider this carefully

Answer (score 2):

You can create a property backed by another one like this:

```kotlin
data class test(
    var a: Int = 0,
) {
    var b: Int
        get() = a + 10
        set(value) {
            a = value - 10
        }
}
```

Or even make it an extension over `test` class.

Just note `b` won't be settable with constructor. it won't be automatically included in `equals()`, `hashCode()` and other methods. It actually makes sense, because it is effectively just a duplicate of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom setter/delegate for `a`, but it can't be added for primary constructor property, so you can't use `data class` here, only a simple one:

```kotlin
class Test(a: Int = 0, var b: Int = 10 + a) {
    var a by Delegates.observable(a) { _, _, newValue -> this.b = 10 + newValue }
}
```

Also, if you want to enforce this relation between `a` and `b` you need to disable direct change of `b` value (including setting in the constructor):

```kotlin
class Test(a: Int = 0) {
    var a by Delegates.observable(a) { _, _, newValue -> this.b = 10 + newValue }
    var b = 10 + a
        private set
}
```